# sum a diagonal array

Tags: arrays, swift

how can i  possible sum in diagonal 3 arrays?

example:

[**6**, 6, **5**]

[10, **5**, 10]

[**3**, 20, **1**]

from left to right, and right to left

6 + 5 + 1 = 12

3 + 5 + 5 = 13

this is how my arrays are declare:

```
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!


 let text : String = text1.text!
    var digits = [Int]()
    for element in text.characters
    {
        digits.append(Int(String(element))!)
    }
    print(digits)
```

this is how my arrays sum in diagonal

```
 let anArray = [[digits],[digits2],[digits3]]
    let size = anArray.count
    for i in 0..<size {
        if anArray[i].count != size {
            print("error")
        }
    }


    var diagSum = 0
    for i in 0..<size {
        for j in 0..<size where i == j {
            diagSum += anArray[i][j] // i have an error here Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let arr1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
var sum = 0
arr1.indices.forEach { sum += arr1[$0][$0] }
```

---

```
arr1.indices.forEach { sum += arr1[$0][arr1.count - 1 - $0] } // not compiled
```

Comment: let arr1 = [[digits],[digits2],[digits3]]
        var sum = 0
        arr1.indices.forEach { sum += arr1[$0][$0] }

same error

Comment: digits is an array , you need `let arr1 = [digits1,digits2,digits3]`

Comment: You can compute the other diagonal by reversing all arrays.

Comment: thanks let arr1 = [digits1,digits2,digits3] did the work